# Esiste la parola spannometrico in italiano?

Tags: word-usage

Oramai di uso comune, mi è posta in dubbio l'esistenza di questa parola. Cercandola online ho constatato che figura su numerosi dizionari ma non ho trovato discussioni della Crusca in merito.

Qualcuno sa confermarmi o smentirmi la presenza di questo vocabolo nella lingua italiana?

Comment: http://sspina.blogspot.ca/2008/06/spannometrico.html   Crusca o no, se ormai il termine è entrato nei dizionari si può dire che esiste...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sì, esiste senz'altro.

Lo riportano vari dizionari: quanto meno lo Zingarelli (definendolo «(*scherz.*) approssimativo, impreciso: *valutazione spannometrica*» e datandolo al 1988), il Grande Dizionario Italiano dell'uso della Utet (citato nell'[articolo](http://sspina.blogspot.ca/2008/06/spannometrico.html) segnalato da Erik vanDoren in un commento) e altri; il Treccani non riporta l'aggettivo ma registra tra i neologismi [spannometria](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/spannometria_(Neologismi)/).

Inoltre, compare numerose volte in rete e qualche decina di volte persino nei libri censiti da [Google Books](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22spannometrico%22&newwindow=1&safe=off&tbm=bks).

Non tragga in inganno l'origine e l'uso scherzoso della parola: una volta che un termine si è diffuso, che sia nato da una trattazione dottissima o da una spiritosaggine, fa parte della lingua a tutti gli effetti.